# How can I get the ISO language code in IOS?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios

How can I get the current ISO language code in IOS?

Comment: Check out the Apple doc for [Internationalization Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Articles/ChoosingLocalizations.html)

Answer (score 3):

`[[NSLocale currentLocale] localeIdentifier]` will give you a string that's closer to what you are looking for.  For my device here in the US, I get "en_US".

If you want a more standard looking "en-US", you can take use `[[[NSLocale currentLocale] localeIdentifier] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"_" withString:@"-"]` instead.

If you just want the language code, you can pass the output of `[[NSLocale currentLocale] localeIdentifier]` to `[NSLocale componentsFromLocaleIdentifier:]` which will give you an NSDictionary back. One of the keys in the dictionary will be `NSLocaleLanguageCode` which will have a NSString object with just the language code.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *isoCode = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];
```

This will return a 2 letter iso code for the selected language on the device. "en" for english, "de" for german, and so on.
I hope that helps!

Comment: btw, Try to print that array. It contains strings with length greater than 2 `"zh-Hans"`. It might hurt to make that assumption.

Comment: You were right. The output is for me: "en,
    fr,
    de,
    "zh-Hans",
    "zh-Hant",
    ja,
    nl,
    it,
    es,
    "es-MX",
    ko,
    pt,
    "pt-PT",
    da,
    fi,
    nb,
    sv,
    ru,
    pl,
    tr,
    uk,
    ar,
    hr,
    cs,
    el,
    he,
    ro,
    sk,
    th,
    id,
    ms,
    "en-GB",
    "en-AU",
    ca,
    hu,
    vi"

Comment: I suggest to update your answer with: [[[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0] substringToIndex:2]

This will always give back a two letter language code.

Comment: @Raphael how can i get the 3 letter iso code i.e. "eng", "abk"?